# How to fix 'else without if' in Netbeans

Tags: java

I am trying to run this simple code in Netbeans and somehow keep getting an 'else without if' error.

I ran this in Eclips as well and there I get the remark that else should be converted into a while which confuses me even more. 
I already did some examples like this and they worked.

I also left out the semi colon at the end of the if statement but it didn't work.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int a = 4;
    int b = 5;
    boolean negative = false;

    if (negative && (a < 0 && b < 0)); 
    {  
    System.out.println("true");
    }
    else((a < 0 && b > 0) || (a > 0 && b < 0));
    {
    System.out.println("false");
    }
```

Comment: `if (negative && (a < 0 && b < 0));` <-- Get rid of the trailing `;` from both the `if` and `else if` statements

Comment: Second problem is that `else` doesn't take any condition. If you want to add one you need another `if(condition)` like `if (isBlueTest) {handle blue} else if(isRedTest) {handle red} else {handle any other cases}`.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is you put a condition to an else statement. You can only put a condition on else if statements

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int a = 4;
    int b = 5;
    boolean negative = false;

    if (negative && (a < 0 && b < 0)) {  
        System.out.println("true");
    } else if((a < 0 && b > 0) || (a > 0 && b < 0)){
        System.out.println("false");
    } else
        .....
}
```

Comment: Don"t say *try*, but explain the problem and the given solution

Comment: It still doesn't work, the error next to the 'else' says: not a statement.